# How to make doxygen copy a folder without changes into generated HTML docs?

Tags: html, doxygen

I have a folder with `bla.html` file and some assets (`*.png` and `*.json`) it it.

I want doxygen to copy it into HTML documentation root.

How to make it do such thing in doxygen configuration file (not using external script)?

Comment: How about (from the documentation / Doxyfile): HTML_EXTRA_FILES The HTML_EXTRA_FILES tag can be used to specify one or more extra images or
other source files which should be copied to the HTML output directory. Note that these files will be copied to
the base HTML output directory. Use the $relpath^ marker in the HTML_HEADER and/or HTML_FOO -
TER files to load these files. In the HTML_STYLESHEET file, use the file name only. Also note that the files
will be copied as-is; there are no commands or markers available.
This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_HTML is set to YES.

Comment: @albert This ought to be an answer.  :)

Comment: @JimPivarski Upon request I did it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Upon request:

How about (from the documentation / Doxyfile):

> HTML_EXTRA_FILES The HTML_EXTRA_FILES tag can be used to specify one
>   or more extra images or other source files which should be copied to
>   the HTML output directory. Note that these files will be copied to the
>   base HTML output directory. Use the $relpath^ marker in the
>   HTML_HEADER and/or HTML_FOOTER files to load these files. In the
>   HTML_STYLESHEET file, use the file name only. Also note that the files
>   will be copied as-is; there are no commands or markers available. This
>   tag requires that the tag GENERATE_HTML is set to YES.

The full doxygen documentation can be found at : http://doxygen.nl/manual/index.html and the referred part at: http://doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_extra_files